# How to extract data of lyr. to shp. file by map extent

Tags: shapefile, layer-file

I have a lyr. connect to a state scale data source. Is it possible to download all the data within the map extent and save as shp. file to my local drive?

Comment: What's your "state scale data source"?  What have you tried?

Comment: Please add some info to your question if you want better answers.

Answer (score 1):

If your 'state scale data source' is a wfs or wfst (web feature service or transactional web feature service), then yes.  Otherwise, you generally cannot download the data.